# Слово не перемещается в центр

Tags: html, css

Слово "Travel" не смещается к центру. Пробовал и `padding` и `margin`, твердо уселся в углу , и лишь только на чуть чуть смещается вправо, после прописки `text-align: center;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1600px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.block {
  /* Style for "Ellipse 1" */
  margin: 400px 300px 700px 400px;
  /*background-color: #80b7b3;*/
}

.travel {
  width: 67px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #273d46;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="travel">
  Travel
</div>



<div class="block">
  <img src="Ellipse_1_copy.png" height="500px" width="500px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы блок располагался по центру экрана, следует классу `.travel` задать ширину: `width: 100%` и `display: flex`, в таком случае, ваш элемент `.travel` будет иметь ширину равную ширине экрана пользователя не зависимо от того какое у него разрешение, после того, как вы добавили свойство `display` и `width` следует выровнять элементы в данном блоке по центру, для этого: прописываем свойство `justify-content: center;` для того, чтобы выровнять элементы в блоке по горизонтали, если хотите выровнять элементы блока и по вертикали, для этого следует прописать данное свойство: `align-items: center;`
Хотел бы отметить, что эти свойства(`justify-content: center;` и `align-items: center;`) работают только при `display: flex`. Если еще будут вопросы - пишите!

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что при добавлении ```text-align:center``` в вашем случае, как вы сказали практически ничего не менялось, потому что у вас была ширина блока ```67px``` и поэтому, когда вы писали  ```text-align:center``` у вас действительно выравнивался текст по центру, но в рамках этих ```67px```

Comment: Очень круто,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если блок с фикс шириной, то задайте ему  `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;` чтобы разместить по центру.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1600px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.block {
  /* Style for "Ellipse 1" */
  margin: 400px 300px 700px 400px;
  /*background-color: #80b7b3;*/
}

.travel {
  width: 67px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #273d46;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="travel">
  Travel
</div>



<div class="block">
  <img src="Ellipse_1_copy.png" height="500px" width="500px">
</div>
```

Comment: Да,работает,спасибо!